# How can I make a call from my action on google?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm building an action for Google Assistant using DialogFlow.

And for this action, I want an intent say "Call X" with which the user can call "X".

Here "X" is not a contact in the user's device but a contact defined within my intent's response.

Is there any option with which I can achieve any of the following for my action?

- Make a Call to X, or atleast
- Open up the dialer with the defined number from my action

Please guide me on this.

Comment: I believe you can do it on any mobile phone these days. I just say OK Google! Call MOM Mobile and it will dial my mom's mobile number.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi Sir I'm asking about making a call from my Actions on Google assistant not from the Google Assistant.

Comment: I am saying why do you want to do that? What is the use case? As we can make calls from assistant.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi An example could be I'm making an action for an institute or business and I want my action to be capable of making a call to that institute or business if the user needs some help without actually knowing or dialing their contact number.

Comment: I don't think it is supported. You may try to create a web link from https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses and use something like <a href="tel:9876543210"></a>

Comment: let us know if it worked ;)

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? It would be great, for instance, to be able to call my company using an Action which would establish the nature of the callers' business and than place a voice  call to a person if that should be appropriate (or dictate a message, send a text, tweet, whatever).

Comment: Yes, that would be much useful! But unfortunately, it's not supported yet.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is Use a Helper Intent Through which you will get the permission from the Phone to make calls and then perform the Action using fullfillment logic.

Comment: Can you explain how can I get permission from the phone to make calls?

And also what code do I need to write for making a call in my fulfilment logic?

Comment: permissions are only for locations and name